# Google AppEngine (GAE) - complete object key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a list of child entities in my datastore.
I query the datastore to get their id and name to show them in a listbox. (I send the long id)
When the user selects an entity I need to get the entity info.
I'm using this:

```
Key parentKey = KeyFactory.createKey(Parent.class.getSimpleName(), parentLongKey);
Key childKey = KeyFactory.createKey(parentKey, Child.class.getSimpleName(), childLongKey);
manager.getObjectById(Child.class, childKey);
```

and it works, but if the child class has it own child class I'll need to create the parent key, the child key and the subchild key???

There is a way to get some id type enough to query the child entity without creating the parents entities???

I tried using the string but has the same problem.
I tried the .toString key version and it has a similar problem

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the stringified version of the whole key, using [keyToString](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.html#keyToString%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key%29) and stringToKey.